# Empathy IM failure to connect in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, empathy, aim

In Ubuntu 11.10 I am trying to use Empathy to connect to an AIM account but it is displaying an error message. Specifically it says "connection cannot be established" when it tries to log in. It had worked the first time I set up empathy and I have confirmed that the account is still active (I can log in on Meebo and the official AIM client). I have tried removing the account configuration and also uninstalling Empathy and Pidgin but it is still not working. I haven't found much useful information in respect to this issue online, was hoping to find a solution here.